# Can I host two MVC3 applications next to each other?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7

Can I have an MVC3 application in ~/priv/, and another in ~/pub?

It seems that if I first put an application in ~/priv/ then when I go to "XXX.XXXXX.com/" it serves the application in ~/priv.  Can I solve this with routes? Is there something I am missing? Please help!

Edit:
To be clear, is there a way that the structure can look like:

```
[root]
  [priv]
  [pub]
```

so that if someone goes to root neither one is seen, if someone goes to root/priv they the priv app and if someone goes to root/pub they get the pub app.

Comment: why would you nest virtual directories/applications within one another?

Comment: One is a proprietary application, and the other is public domain.  They don't have to be nested.  One could be in ~/pub/ and the other could be in ~/priv/.  The only problem is that they both would try to take over ~/.  Is there a way to prevent that from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure of several things:

- The virtual directories [pub] and [priv] must **each** be configured as an Application in IIS.
- If [root] is configured as an application, any applications in sub folders will inherit the values from web.config, even if they run under a different app pools. Make sure this is not causing a conflict or unexpected behavior.
- Check for the setting `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests=true`. If [root] is configured as an Application, it may be intercepting the call fro IIS before it gets to a child application. You may want to add the following to the web.config of [root]  (but make sure to override this in [pub] and [priv]:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <configuration>
      <system.webServer>
      <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">
              <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
          </modules>
      </system.webServer>
  </configuration>
  ```
- Then, in web.config for [pub] and [priv] you can add:

  ```
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" />
  </modules>
  ```

Comment: root is empty, and has no files in it, although the provider may be defining it as an application somewhere that I do not have access to.

Comment: Then you would need to add a web.config to it.

Comment: That is a very good idea / point! Can you edit your answer to show what the web.config file would need to have in it aside from just the module definition, or would a blank web.config with just the module definition work?

Comment: @TravisJ I changed the sample configuration for root to show a minimal web.config.

Answer (score 3):

You can create multiple applications under one site, and have them use different aliases.

Create a new website in IIS Manager.
Right click on that website, and choose 'Add Application...' giving the alias 'priv', and repeat that process for your other 'pub' site.

Then you can hit the predict site via XXX.XXXXX.com/priv/mycontoller/myaction and the other via XXX.XXXXX.com/pub/mycontoller/myaction.

I'd imagine that you'd need to create a new site for this in IIS, rather than just adding an application to an existing ASP.Net MVC site - as I imagine that that would confuse the routing.

Comment: Be sure not to deploy either of your applications to the root of your website and things will work fine. As StanK has described, create your root site, then create seperate "Applications" inside of the site.

Comment: I do not have access to IIS Manager, this site is hosted through a hosting company.

Answer (score 2):

You can create sub-domains for each application.

Comment: This is not a bad solution, but is it the only way? Each sub-domain would have to have its own hosting.

Comment: It depends o your hosting plan. I use IX and they offer unlimited sub-domains for a very reasonable rate. You may want to check with your ISP.

Answer (score 0):

If you can you merge the public and private apps in one web application you can take advantage of Areas in Asp.net MVC.

In this way you can have Areas or Module to divide the application in smaller grouping (in your case a priv area and a pub area)
In fact an Area is a complete MVC structure in you application.

[Grouping Controllers with ASP.NET MVC](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/04/areas-in-aspnetmvc.aspx)

[App Areas in ASP.NET MVC, take 2](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/11/05/app-areas-in-aspnet-mvc-take-2/)

[Walkthrough: Organizing an ASP.NET MVC Application using Areas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793.aspx)

Comment: Although it is possible to code/content/filesystem/completely couple projects together, this is not what I had in mind.  You see, this example is small in that I want to be able to deploy several, if not many, applications in separate folders.  I do not want to recompile to add an application, and I sure don't want other people developing applications to have access to the code of the entire application base.